# trying to figure out this azure static website/app scenario

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm trying to establish a proper domain association and ci/cd process for my React app on Azure.  I can create a static website on the $web Container of a Storage account in Azure.  And then I can Deploy the React website from the /build dir of my React app to the $web Container on the Azure Storage account via a VS Code extension ("Deploy to Static Website via Azure Storage").  This approach allows me to easily deploy app builds to the Static Website on Azure.

One twist is that I'm trying to associate a custom domain name that's hosted in my Google Domains account.  I didn't see a way to do this offhand through the setup that I described in the first paragraph.  But based on a basic google, I found a walkthrough vid which showed how this setup could be achieved on a Static Web App which existed *independently* of a Storage Account $web container.  In this scenario, this configuration is possible through a "Custom Domains" nav item.

I haven't used Azure extensively but in the past I only implemented static websites as described in the first paragraph.  When I go to the static website that I created as described in the first paragraph, I don't see the "Custom Domains" menu item available to me.  Can you provide any insight into this?  Am I overlooking that option somewhere?  Or is this style of static website basically considered a "quick and dirty" setup for internal use only?  Whereas a static web *app* is needed to connect with an external domain name?

These Azure object types have similar names but they appear to have some differences since a search for Static Web Apps in the top search bar doesn't return the static website that I created on the Storage Account $web container.

But one limitation with the second approach ("static web app") is that it appears that I'm only able to Deploy to static web*site*s via the VS Code extension.  I did a quick google on Bitbucket pipelines for CI/CD and the google results appear to indicate that an auto-deploy pipeline between Bitbucket and Azure is only possible when the pipeline is hosted on Linux.  Is this a non-issue if I'm using Bitbucket Cloud?  I'm hoping that an Azure expert can provide some clarity on these things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Azure Storage Account "Static Website" feature to host a static website. In this case you have to use Azure CDN for https Custom Domain integraiton as stated here: [Mapping a custom domain to a static website URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website#mapping-a-custom-domain-to-a-static-website-url)

The deployment Model should be as easy as uploading content to Azure blob Storage. I am not aware of the pipeline Tasks in Bitbucket Cloud, but any build agent that supports Azure CLI (az storage azcopy blob upload) should do.

You can also create a "Static web app" Resource in Azure. You can chose between Free and Standard Pricing Models (at the time of this writing). In this case mounting a Custom Domain is supported directly on the resource. Setting up deployment directly from git is also possible for some platforms. But in general you can follow this article: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/static-web-apps/bitbucket.md